# How to download already purchased Xbox One games data on PC?

Tags: xbox-one

I have some games already purchased on Xbox One. Games Like Witcher 3 and GTA5. But Due to Lack of Internet speed I was not able do download those large game at my home. And I want to download games file from my Office PC. So my question is: How to Download already purchased xbox game on PC? After Searching on Internet I managed to find the process of transferring game data to XBox One from PC.

[Here is the Link.](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/console-guides/xbox-one-guides/13584-copy-extract-content-xbox-one-usb-formatted-drive-windows-pc.html)

Comment: If you read the link you posted, it says that it doesn't work anymore. Furthermore, you can't purchase most games on Xbox One and get it on Windows for free. You can games that make use of cross play like Recore and Gear of War 4, but not for games like GTA V and The Witcher 3.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, I just want to download the game data of Xbox One and then transfer the game data to XBox One. That's it. I don't want to play on PC.  I want to play on Xbox. Only issue with me is i can't download games at home on Xbox One,  for now ofcourse.

Comment: You should remove the *How to Download already purchased xbox game on PC?* part from your question then because that is what you are saying in addition to your other question.

Comment: I just wrote it to be clear that I'm not enabling piracy. By the way,  thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot download games on the PC and then transfer them to the Xbox One.

You can transfer game data, that is, save games for your profile, from the PC to the Xbox One. However, this process is automated and requires no intervention on your end.

Answer (score 1):

I have found these steps on Web:

1. Attach an external hard disk to Xbox and make it default
2. Download about 1 MB of your game and pause it, then unplug hard disk from Xbox
3. Attach hard disk to PC and in PC mode open it in explorer (by [XBOX One External Storage Device Converter](https://digiex.net/attachments/xbox-one-external-storage-device-converter-v1-rar.13749/) )
4. You will see three new files there:

   - First file is a huge file that is game data (partial because paused ...). file name is important
   - Second file is xvi file, I don't know what that is, maybe download progress is stored in it.
   - The third file is about 1 KB
5. Open notepad and drop the third file into note pad. Remove extra spaces with replace command. Two links to game data from Microsoft servers is there.
6. Now you can download it with PC
7. After download completed, rename it to the first file and copy to external HDD and delete the other two files
8. Enable Xbox mode, remove HDD from PC
9. Before attaching HDD to your Xbox, begin downloading the game again on Xbox (internal HDD) and pause it again
10. Attach external HDD to Xbox and go to my games and select manage game. You will see the game twice, one on internal that is partial and second on external that is complete with full game size displayed
11. Cancel the internal installation
12. Move or copy game from external to internal

    - Steps 9 and 11 can be omitted

Comment: This process worked but is missing one KEY piece of information. The downloaded game data file MUST have the same timestamp as the remote file or the hash check will fail and the xbox will try to start an update of the game. I used curl to fetch the last modified date of the remote file `curl -s -v -X HEAD $url 2>&1 | grep '^< Last-Modified:'` and touch to set the timestamp of the local file `touch -t YYYYMMDDHHmm.ss $filename`. For reference, here is the source for these instructions. https://digiex.net/threads/download-xbox-one-games-on-a-pc-and-transfer-to-xbox-one.15279/